# python recursive vectorization with timeseries

Tags: python, recursion, numpy, time-series, vectorization

I have a Timeseries (s) which need to be processed recursively to get a timeseries result (res). Here is my sample code:

```
res=s.copy()*0  
res[1]=k # k is a constant  
for i in range(2,len(s)):  
    res[i]=c1*(s[i]+s[i-1])/2 +c2*res[i-1]+c3*res[i-2]
```

where c1,c2,c3 are constants. It works properly but I'd like to use vectorization and I tried with:

```
res[2:]=c1*(s[2:]+s[1:-1])/2+c2*res[1:-1]+c3*res[0:-2]
```

but I get  "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1016) (1018) "
if I try with

```
res=c1*(s[2:]+s[1:-1])/2+c2*res[1:-1]+c3*res[0:-2]
```

doesn't give any error, but I don't get a correct result, because res[0] and res[1] have to be initialized before the calculation will take place.
Is there a way to process it with vectorization?
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Update this with the values you are using for the constants.  If you make it copy-paste runnable, you'll probably get more help.  Also - do you know about numpy?

Comment: Is this because you want to speed things up? (memoization could speed up stuff like this if you rewrite it a bit i guess?)

Comment: For such problems I like using numexpr (http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) often improves speed significantly with little effort.

Comment: First line is better written as `res = np.zeros_like(s)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression

```
    res[i] = c1*(s[i] + s[i-1])/2 + c2*res[i-1] + c3*res[i-2]
```

says that `res` is the output of a linear filter (or ARMA process) with input `s`.  Several libraries have functions for computing this.  Here's how you can use the scipy function [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html).

From inspection of the recurrence relation, we get the coefficients of the numerator (`b`) and denominator (`a`) of the filter's transfer function:

```
b = c1 * np.array([0.5, 0.5])
a = np.array([1, -c2, -c3])
```

We'll also need an appropriate initial condition for `lfilter` to handle `res[:2] == [0, k]`.  For this, we use [`scipy.signal.lfiltic`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfiltic.html):

```
zi = lfiltic(b, a, [k, 0], x=s[1::-1])
```

In the simplest case, one would call `lfilter` like this:

```
y = lfilter(b, a, s)
```

With an initial condition `zi`, we use:

```
y, zo = lfilter(b, a, s, zi=zi)
```

However, to exactly match the calculation provided in the question, we need the output `y` to start with `[0, k]`.  So we'll allocate an array `y`, initialize the first two elements with `[0, k]`, and assign the output of `lfilter` to `y[2:]`:

```
y = np.empty_like(s)
y[:2] = [0, k]
y[2:], zo = lfilter(b, a, s[2:], zi=zi)
```

Here's a complete script with the original loop and with `lfilter`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter, lfiltic


c1 = 0.125
c2 = 0.5
c3 = 0.25

np.random.seed(123)
s = np.random.rand(8)
k = 3.0

# Original version (edited lightly)

res = np.zeros_like(s)
res[1] = k  # k is a constant  
for i in range(2, len(s)):  
    res[i] = c1*(s[i] + s[i-1])/2 + c2*res[i-1] + c3*res[i-2]


# Using scipy.signal.lfilter

# Coefficients of the filter's transfer function.
b = c1 * np.array([0.5, 0.5])
a = np.array([1, -c2, -c3])

# Create the initial condition of the filter such that
#     y[:2] == [0, k]
zi = lfiltic(b, a, [k, 0], x=s[1::-1])

y = np.empty_like(s)
y[:2] = [0, k]
y[2:], zo = lfilter(b, a, s[2:], zi=zi)

np.set_printoptions(precision=5)
print "res:", res
print "y:  ", y
```

The output is:

```
res: [ 0.       3.       1.53206  1.56467  1.24477  1.08496  0.94142  0.84605]
y:   [ 0.       3.       1.53206  1.56467  1.24477  1.08496  0.94142  0.84605]
```

---

`lfilter` accepts an `axis` argument, so you can filter an array of signals with a single call.  `lfiltic` does not have an `axis` argument, so setting up the initial conditions requires a loop.  The following script shows an example.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter, lfiltic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Parameters
c1 = 0.2
c2 = 1.1
c3 = -0.5
k = 1

# Create an array of signals for the demonstration.
np.random.seed(123)
nsamples = 50
nsignals = 4
s = np.random.randn(nsamples, nsignals)

# Coefficients of the filter's transfer function.
b = c1 * np.array([0.5, 0.5])
a = np.array([1, -c2, -c3])

# Create the initial condition of the filter for each signal
# such that
#     y[:2] == [0, k]
# We need a loop here, because lfiltic is not vectorized.
zi = np.empty((2, nsignals))
for i in range(nsignals):
    zi[:, i] = lfiltic(b, a, [k, 0], x=s[1::-1, i])

# Create the filtered signals.
y = np.empty_like(s)
y[:2, :] = np.array([0, k]).reshape(-1, 1)
y[2:, :], zo = lfilter(b, a, s[2:], zi=zi, axis=0)

# Plot the filtered signals.
plt.plot(y, linewidth=2, alpha=0.6)
ptp = y.ptp()
plt.ylim(y.min() - 0.05*ptp, y.max() + 0.05*ptp)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Plot:

[image: filtered signals]

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution is much more efficient and faster than mine! Is there a way to apply it to a dataframe of signals (one signal for each dataframe column) all at once, without iterate the dataframe columns and calling lfilter every time?

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to handle an array of signals.