# Can I use numpy to speed this loop?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Good evening,

I am trying to speed up the loop in this code.  I have read through the numpy docs but to no avail. np.accumulate looks like it is almost what I need, but not quite.

What could I do to speed up the loop?

```
import numpy as np

N       = 1000
AR_part = np.random.randn(N+1)
s2      = np.ndarray(N+1)
s2[0]   = 1.0

beta = 1.3

old_s2  = s2[0]
for t in range( 1, N+1 ):               
    s2_t    = AR_part[ t-1 ] + beta * old_s2
    s2[t]   = s2_t        
    old_s2  = s2_t
```

In response to Warren, I updated my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter, lfiltic

N       = 1000
AR_part = np.random.randn(N+1)

beta = 1.3

def method1( AR_part):
    s2      = np.empty_like(AR_part)
    s2[0]   = 1.0
    old_s2  = s2[0]
    for t in range( 1, N+1 ):               
        s2_t    = AR_part[ t-1 ] + beta * old_s2
        s2[t]   = s2_t        
        old_s2  = s2_t
    return s2

def method2( AR_part):
    y = np.empty_like(AR_part)
    b = np.array([0, 1])
    a = np.array([1, -beta])

    # Initial condition for the linear filter.
    zi = lfiltic(b, a, [1.0], AR_part[:1])

    y[:1] = 1.0
    y[1:], zo = lfilter(b, a, AR_part[1:], zi=zi)

    return y    

s2 = method1( AR_part )
y = method2( AR_part )
np.alltrue( s2==y )
```

Timing the code:

```
%timeit method1( AR_part )
100 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop
%timeit method2( AR_part )
10000 loops, best of 3: 129 us per loop
```

That shows that Warren's method is over 10 times faster!  Very impressive!

Answer (score 5):

Your recurrence relation is linear, so it can be viewed as a linear filter.  You can use `scipy.signal.lfilter` to compute `s2`.  I recently answered a similar question here: [python recursive vectorization with timeseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336794/python-recursive-vectorization-with-timeseries/21338665)

Here's a script that shows how to use `lfilter` to compute your series:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter, lfiltic


np.random.seed(123)

N       = 4
AR_part = np.random.randn(N+1)
s2      = np.ndarray(N+1)
s2[0]   = 1.0

beta = 1.3

old_s2  = s2[0]
for t in range( 1, N+1 ):               
    s2_t    = AR_part[ t-1 ] + beta * old_s2
    s2[t]   = s2_t        
    old_s2  = s2_t


# Compute the result using scipy.signal.lfilter.

# Transfer function coefficients.
# `b` is the numerator, `a` is the denominator.
b = np.array([0, 1])
a = np.array([1, -beta])

# Initial condition for the linear filter.
zi = lfiltic(b, a, s2[:1], AR_part[:1])

# Apply lfilter to AR_part.
y = np.empty_like(AR_part)
y[:1] = s2[:1]
y[1:], zo = lfilter(b, a, AR_part[1:], zi=zi)

# Compare the results
print "s2 =", s2
print "y  =", y
```

Output:

```
s2 = [ 1.          0.2143694   1.27602566  1.94181186  1.0180607 ]
y  = [ 1.          0.2143694   1.27602566  1.94181186  1.0180607 ]
```

Comment: It's over 10 times faster!  Very impressive!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure there is much to do to speed up the loop... The only way I see would be to avoid the recursion, ie compute s2[t] "directly" for each t. But this is expensive as well...

You have

```
s2[t] = AR_part[t-1] + beta * s2[t-1]
= AR_part[t-1] + beta * (AR_part[t-2] + beta * s2[t-2])
= AR_part[t-1] + beta * AR_part[t-2] + beta^2 * s2[t-2]
= np.dot( AR[:t-1], beta_powers[-(t-1):]  )
```

Where beta_powers contains [beta^1000, beta^999, ... 1.0]. You can create beta_powers this way:

```
np.power(beta, np,arange(1000))[::-1].
```

But I can't see a way to compute that stuff faster than what your loop does...

However you can rewrite it:

```
for t in range(N):
    s2[t+1] = AR_part[t] + beta * s2[t]
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with GHL that you won't get much more performance (though if `N` was really big, and you were only computing some parts of the vector `s2`, definitely use his method), but here's a different way to do what you're looking at:

```
import numpy as np

N       = 1000
AR_part = np.random.randn(N+1)
beta = 1.3


def seq_gen(beta, constants, first_element = 1.0):
    next_element = first_element
    yield next_element
    for j in constants:
        next_element = j + beta * next_element
        yield next_element

s2 = np.array([j for j in seq_gen(beta, AR_part, 1.0)])
```