# optimizing low pass filter smoothing code for activity recognition

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, accelerometer

I'm trying to implement a low pass filter on accelerometer data(with x-acceleration(ax), y-acceleration(ay), z-acceleration(az))

I have calculated my alpha to be 0.2

DC component along the x direction is calculated using the formula

new_ax[n] = (1-alpha)*new_ax[n-1] + (alpha * ax[n])

I'm able to calculate this for a small dataset with few thousand records. But I have a dataset with a million records and it takes forever to run with the below code. I would appreciate any help to improvise my code for time complexity.

```
### df is a pandas dataframe object
n_ax = []
seq = range(0, 1000000, 128)
for w in range(len(seq)):
   prev_x = 0
   if w+1 <= len(seq):
      subdf = df[seq[w]:seq[w+1]]
      for i in range(len(subdf)):
          n_ax.append((1-alpha)*prev_x + (alpha*subdf.ax[i]))
          prev_x = n_ax[i]
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336794/python-recursive-vectorization-with-timeseries and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391467/can-i-use-numpy-to-speed-this-loop

Comment: @Warren: Thanks for directing me to the right page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it seems you don't need

```
if w+1 <= len(seq):
```

the w variable will not surpass len(seq).

So to decrease time processing just use numpy module:

```
import numpy;
```

Here you will find arrays and methods that are much faster than built-in list. For example instead of looping trough every element in a numpy array to do some processing you can apply a numpy function directly on the array and get the results in seconds rather than hours. as an example:

```
data = numpy.arange(0, 1000000, 128);
shiftData = numpy.arange(128, 1000000, 128);
result = (1-alpha)*data[:-1] + shiftdata;
```

Check some tutorials on numpy. I use this module for processing image data and by comparison looping through lists would have taken me 2 weeks to processes 5000+ image while using numpy types takes maximum 2 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. I'm going to try your approach

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using python 2.7.

- Use xrange.
- Computing `len(seq)` inside the loop is not necessary, since its value is not changing.
- Accessing `seq` it is not really needed, since you can compute it on the fly.
- You don't really need the `if` statement, since in your code it always evaluate to true (`w in range(len(seq))` means `w` maximium value will be `len(seq)-1`).
- The slicing you are doing to get `subdf` is not really necessary, since you can access directly df (and slicing creates a new list).

See the code below.

```
n_ax = []
SUB_SAMPLE = 128
SAMPLE_LEN = 1000000
seq_len = SAMPLE_LEN/SUB_SAMPLE
for w in xrange(seq_len):
   prev_x = 0
   for i in xrange(w*SUB_SAMPLE,(w+1)*SUB_SAMPLE):
       new_x = (1-alpha)*prev_x + (alpha*df.ax[i])
       n_ax.append(new_x)
       prev_x = new_x
```

I cannot think any other obvious optimization. If this is still slow, perhaps you should consider copying `df` data to a python native data type. If these are all floats, use python `array` which gives very good performance.

And if you still need better performance, you can try parallelism with the `multiprocessing` module, or write a C module that takes an array in memory and does the computation, and call it with `ctypes` python library.