# Python Pandas, using the previous value in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that use b(t-1) variable like:

```
def test_b(a,b_1):
     return a + b_1
```

Assume the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':np.nan})
```

I am assigning the b_1 initial value:

```
df['b'].ix[0]=0
```

and then (using my Matlab experience), i use the loop:

```
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    df['b'].ix[i] = test_b(df['a'].ix[i],df['b'].ix[i-1])
```

output:

```
  a|b
0|1|0
1|2|2
2|3|5
```

Is it a more elegant way to do the same?

Comment: show what you want the output to be

Comment: jeff, i getting the output i want. I just want to see if another way exist with pandas , like apply or shift. I tried but i couldn't figure out

Comment: no, what I mean is best to actually *show* the output in the question

Answer (score 1):

You never want to do assignments like this, as this is [chained indexing](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

This is a recurrent relation, so not easy way ATM to do this in a super performant manner, though see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/enhancingperf.html).

[here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4567) is an open issue about this with a pointer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336794/python-recursive-vectorization-with-timeseries/21338665) which uses `ifilter` to solve the relation.

Comment: `for x in df.index[1:]:
 df.loc[x, 'b'] = df.loc[x, 'a'] + df.loc[x - 1, 'b']`..... Is this also bad? I've never quite got to the bottom of this issue...

Comment: but I am terrified of it!

Comment: that's ok, but would be really slow on a big frame (better to create a list then assign it all at once