# Recursive definitions in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a time-series `A` holding several values. I need to obtain a series `B` that is defined algebraically as follows:

```
B[t] = a * A[t] + b * B[t-1]
```

where we can assume `B[0] = 0`, and `a` and `b` are real numbers.

Is there any way to do this type of recursive computation in Pandas? Or do I have no choice but to loop in Python as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407984/is-a-for-loop-necessary-if-elements-of-the-a-numpy-vector-are-dependant-upon-t)?

As an example of input:

```
> A = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10,))

0   -0.310354
1   -0.739515
2   -0.065390
3    0.214966
4   -0.605490
5    1.293448
6   -3.068725
7   -0.208818
8    0.930881
9    1.669210
```

Comment: here the open issue to cythonize it: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4567, but some links are their as well

Comment: You can use `scipy.signal.lfilter`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336794/python-recursive-vectorization-with-timeseries for an example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, you can use [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html).  In this case (assuming `A` is a one-dimensional numpy array), all you need is:

```
B = lfilter([a], [1.0, -b], A)
```

Here's a complete script:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter


np.random.seed(123)

A = np.random.randn(10)
a = 2.0
b = 3.0

# Compute the recursion using lfilter.
# [a] and [1, -b] are the coefficients of the numerator and
# denominator, resp., of the filter's transfer function.
B = lfilter([a], [1, -b], A)

print B

# Compare to a simple loop.
B2 = np.empty(len(A))
for k in range(0, len(B2)):
    if k == 0:
        B2[k] = a*A[k]
    else:
        B2[k] = a*A[k] + b*B2[k-1]

print B2

print "max difference:", np.max(np.abs(B2 - B))
```

The output of the script is:

```
[ -2.17126121e+00  -4.51909273e+00  -1.29913212e+01  -4.19865530e+01
  -1.27116859e+02  -3.78047705e+02  -1.13899647e+03  -3.41784725e+03
  -1.02510099e+04  -3.07547631e+04]
[ -2.17126121e+00  -4.51909273e+00  -1.29913212e+01  -4.19865530e+01
  -1.27116859e+02  -3.78047705e+02  -1.13899647e+03  -3.41784725e+03
  -1.02510099e+04  -3.07547631e+04]
max difference: 0.0
```

---

Another example, in IPython, using a pandas DataFrame instead of a numpy array:

If you have

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame([1, 7, 9, 5], columns=['A'])

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
   A
0  1
1  7
2  9
3  5
```

and you want to create a new column, `B`, such that `B[k] = A[k] + 2*B[k-1]` (with `B[k] == 0` for k < 0), you can write

```
In [14]: df['B'] = lfilter([1], [1, -2], df['A'].astype(float))

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
   A   B
0  1   1
1  7   9
2  9  27
3  5  59
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks Warren. I took classes in signals & systems (Oppenheim's book), and this feels so right. I will look into this answer carefully, since it looks like it is the right way to solve the problem. I presume this approach can only handle linear recursions, correct?

Comment: Yes, only linear.  (The `l` in `lfilter` stands for `linear`.)