# Recursion: IIR filter with `scipy.lfilter`

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, recursion, scipy

Given some data `x`:

```
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader as dr
x = np.squeeze(dr('DTWEXB', 'fred').dropna().values)
```

I want to calculate another vector `y` as follows:

[image]

Where *alpha* equals 0.03, in this case.

Can I do this with [`scipy.lfilter?`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html).  Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267809/recursive-definitions-in-pandas), but in that case the starting value of the result is 0 and that is throwing something off.

My attempt:

```
from scipy.signal import lfilter
a = 0.03
b = 1 - a
y0 = x[0]
y = lfilter([a], [y0, -b], x)
```

The results should be:

```
true_y = np.empty(len(x))
for k in range(0, len(true_y)):
    if k == 0:
        true_y[k] = x[0]
    else:
        true_y[k] = a*x[k] + b*true_y[k-1]
print(true_y)
[ 101.1818      101.176862    101.16819314 ...,  120.9813121   120.92484874
  120.85786628]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct arguments for the coefficients of the transfer function are `[a]` and `[1, -b]`.

To handle your desired initial condition, you can create the correct initial state for the filter using [`scipy.signal.lfiltic`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfiltic.html):

```
zi = lfiltic([a], [1, -b], y=[x[0]])
```

Then call `lfilter` with the `zi` argument:

```
y, zo = lfilter([a], [1, -b], x, zi=zi)
```

Here are an `x`, `y` (computed using `lfilter` with `zi`), and your `true_y`:

```
In [37]: x
Out[37]: array([ 3.,  1.,  2.,  0., -1.,  2.])

In [38]: y
Out[38]: 
array([ 3.        ,  2.94      ,  2.9118    ,  2.824446  ,  2.70971262,
        2.68842124])

In [39]: true_y
Out[39]: 
array([ 3.        ,  2.94      ,  2.9118    ,  2.824446  ,  2.70971262,
        2.68842124])
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the z-transform of your filter, that gives you the values for the numerator `b` and denominator `a`:

```
       alpha
y(z) = ------------------ x(z)
       1 - (1-alpha) z^-1
```

So you run

```
import scipy.signal
x[0] /= alpha
y = scipy.signal.lfilter([alpha], [1, - 1 + alpha], x)
```

Which yields

```
array([ 101.1818    ,  101.176862  ,  101.16819314, ...,  120.9813121 ,
        120.92484874,  120.85786628])
```

Note I have scaled `x[0]` to account for the initial condition you wanted.

Comment: Seems to be on the right track but something is off.  The result `y` should equal `true_y` from above.  I also get an error from setting `a[0]=0` i.e. `[0, 1 - alpha]` (`ValueError: BUG: filter coefficient a[0] == 0 not supported yet`)

Comment: The recurrence relation can be written `y[k] - (1 - a)*y[k-1] = a*x[k]`.  Take the z-transform of *that* and solve for `Y(z)` to get the transfer function.

Comment: I need to brush up my z Transform skills it seems :-D

Comment: This works in addition to @WarrenWeckesser's answer.  I would just suggest `lfilter([a], [1., -1. + a], np.insert(x[1:], 0, x[0] / a))` to avoid modifying `x` inplace.